# Replacing values in certain list in nested lists

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I am writing a program for a crayon manufacturer. They have 4 packs in stock (for now as it is a good starting point for debugging). I have shown that in a list:

```
colors=[['pink','green','blue'],['blue','green','red'],['pink',blue','yellow'],['orange','pink','yellow']]
```

I want to change the colors of crayons in two packs where green is in the middle to get packs with more variety of colors.
First I find all the packs with green in the middle:

```
packsfound = []

for pack in colors:
 if pack[1]=="green":
     packsfound.append(pack)

print("packs with one:",packsfound)
```

Then I remove the packs I selected from stock (colors) so they can be modified and put back later.

```
try:
 for pack in packsfound:
  colors.remove(pack)
except Exception as e:
  print(e)
  pass
```

Then I do the replacement:

```
for pack in packsfound:
try:
 for i, color in enumerate(packsfound):
     position=color.index("green")
     print("replace at:",position)
     break

 pack[position]="yellow"
 print("replaced rows:",packsfound)
except Exception as e:
 print(e)
 pass
```

Then I append the modified lists back to colors so they are new in stock

```
try:
 for pack in packsfound:        
  colors.append(pack)
except Exception as e:
  print(e)
  pass

print(colors)
```

The problem is that it only goes through the first list and replaces the first green. Then the program says green is not in list and doesn't replace the second green:

```
packs with one: [['pink', 'green', 'blue'], ['blue', 'green', 'red']]
replace at: 1
replaced rows: [['pink', 'yellow', 'blue'], ['blue', 'green', 'red']]
'green' is not in list
[['pink', 'blue', 'yellow'], ['orange', 'pink', 'yellow'], ['pink', 'yellow', 'blue'], ['blue', 'green', 'red']]
```

I have tried many things like moving the try and except and moving the replacement lines in and out of loops, adding break and pass but nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is mistake in replacement loop. The way you put the break statement only allow one iteration of the loop. You can use this loop:

```
for pack in packsfound:
    try:
        position = pack.index('green')
        print("replace at:",position)
        pack[position]="yellow"
        print("replaced rows:",packsfound)
except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the elements in the list, its easier to build a new list and return that. Using simple `list comprehension` with `if/else` :

```
>>> mid = int( len(colors[0])/2 )
>>> [ color[:mid]+['yellow']+color[mid+1:] if color[mid]=='green' else color for color in colors ]
=> [['pink', 'yellow', 'blue'], ['blue', 'yellow', 'red'], ['pink', 'blue', 'yellow'], ['orange', 'pink', 'yellow']]
```

***NOTE TO OP:*** This is considering that you want to replace only the color with `green` in  `middle` with `yellow`. If otherwise, all the 'green' elements need to be replaced with `yellow`, use replace.

***NOTE TO OP:*** And this is in case of the odd number of colors in a single set. Otherwise, the middle for even are two elements, and so change the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your replacement step is the issue. It looks like you're making a mistake when you're trying to enumerate the nested list. I'm not sure why you're trying to enumerate the lists when you are already using the `.index()` to get the index of the color value you're searching for.

```
packsfound = [['pink', 'green', 'blue'], ['blue', 'green', 'red']]

for pack in packsfound:
  try:
    for color in pack:
      position = pack.index('green')
      print("replace at: ", position)
      break
    pack[position] = 'yellow'
    print("replaced rows: ", packsfound)
  except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    pass
```

Please excuse my change of variable names. This outputs:

```
replace at:  1
replaced rows:  [['pink', 'yellow', 'blue'], ['blue', 'green', 'red']]
replace at:  1
replaced rows:  [['pink', 'yellow', 'blue'], ['blue', 'yellow', 'red']]
```

Comment: Heh... same response as @Toothless. Beat by 12 seconds! xD